# Select statement from database

Tags: php, mysql

Im struggling with the following code. My final aim is just to create a short div that displays the information from table in my database. It's not working however. Do I also have to connect to the specific database?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>


<?php

$dbName = 'localhost';
$userName = 'root';
$passWord = 'mysql';


 $conn = mysql_connect($dbName, $userName, $passWord);

// Check connection
 if (!$conn) 

{
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

echo "Connected successfully";
?>



 <div id="displayAuthor">

<?php

$sql_statement = "
SELECT ssn, lastname, firstname 
  FROM author 
 ORDER 
    BY lastname, firstname
";

$result = mysql_query($sql_statement);

$outputDisplay = "";

if(!$result)
{
    $outputDisplay .= "Error";
} else

{
    $outputDisplay = "<h3> Table author data </h3>";
    $outputDisplay .= "<tr><th>SSN</th> <th>Last name </th> <th> First name</th> </tr>";
    $numberResults = mysql_num_rows($result);

    for ($i=0; $i<$numberResults; $i++)
    {
        //Dit is een counter van hoeveel rijen het uiteindelijk was.

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $ssn = $row['ssn'];
        $lastname = $row['lastname'];
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];

        $outputDisplay .="<td>".$ssn."</td>";   
        $outputDisplay .="<td>".$lastname."</td>";
        $outputDisplay .="<td>".$firstname."</td>";

        $outputDisplay .= "</tr>";
    }
$outputDisplay .="</table>";

}
print $outputDisplay;
?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to select your database using mysql_select_db. But usage of mysql_* functions not recommended. Use pdo or mysqli_* functions instead.

Comment: Throw this away and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli); then, ask again.

Comment: You can either connect to a specific database or you can specify the database when you specify the table, i.e. `FROM MyDatabase.MyTable` in your Query

Comment: Use this example: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#example-1761

Comment: What Jack means is that the library you are using is no longer maintained, and it doesn't have the newer features such as parameterisation, which you can use to defend yourself against popular hacking techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
 <?php

         $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mysql') or  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
         $db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die("Couldn't select database.");
        echo "Connected successfully";
        ?>

       <div id="displayAuthor">
    <?php

        $sql_statement = "SELECT ssn, lastname, firstname FROM author ORDER BY lastname ASC";
        $result = mysql_query($sql_statement);

        if(!$result)
           $outputDisplay .= "Error";
        else
        {
            $outputDisplay = "<h3> Table author data </h3>";
            $outputDisplay .= "<tr><th>SSN</th> <th>Last name </th> <th> First name</th> </tr>";
            $numberResults = mysql_num_rows($result);

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
                $outputDisplay .="<tr><td>".$row['ssn']."</td>";   
                $outputDisplay .="<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
                $outputDisplay .="<td>".$row['firstname']."</td></tr>";
            }
        $outputDisplay .="</table>";

        }
        echo $outputDisplay;
        ?>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>


<?php

$dbName = 'localhost';
$userName = 'root';
$passWord = 'mysql';


 $conn = mysql_connect($dbName, $userName, $passWord);

// Check connection
 if (!$conn) 

{
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

echo "Connected successfully";
?>



 <div id="displayAuthor">

<?php

$sql_statement = "SELECT ssn, lastname, firstname FROM author ORDER BY lastname, firstname ";

$result = mysql_query($sql_statement);
     = mysql_num_rows($result);
$outputDisplay = "";

if($numberResults==0)
{
    $outputDisplay .= "No Data";
} 
else
{
$outputDisplay="";
    $outputDisplay. = "<h3> Table author data </h3>";
    $outputDisplay .= "<table><tr><th>SSN</th> <th>Last name </th> <th> First name</th> </tr>";


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result);)
    {
        //Dit is een counter van hoeveel rijen het uiteindelijk was.

       $ssn = $row['ssn'];
        $lastname = $row['lastname'];
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];

        $outputDisplay .="<tr><td>".$ssn."</td>";   
        $outputDisplay .="<td>".$lastname."</td>";
        $outputDisplay .="<td>".$firstname."</td>";

        $outputDisplay .= "</tr>";
    }
$outputDisplay .="</table>";

}
print $outputDisplay;
?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```